# Find the coefficient of the power series $[x^3](1-x)^{-1}(1-2x)^6$

Tags: combinatorics, summation

I need to find $[x^3](1-x)^{-1}(1-2x)^6$, where $[x^3]$ means the coefficent of the $[x^3]$ term. here's what I've done:

> $[x^3](1-x)^{-1}(1-2x)^6=[x^3](\sum_{k=0}^6 {6\choose k}(-2x)^k)(\sum_{m=0}^\infty {m\choose 0}x^m)$
>
> $= \sum_{k=0}^6 {6\choose k}(-2)^k[x^{3-k} ](\sum_{m=0}^\infty {m\choose 0}x^m)$
>
> $= \sum_{k=0}^3 {6\choose k}(-2)^k[x^{3-k} ](\sum_{m=0}^\infty {m\choose 0}x^m)$ since we need $3-k \geq 0$
>
> $= \sum_{k=0}^3 ({6\choose k}(-2)^k {3-k\choose 0})$
>
> $= \sum_{k=0}^3 ({6\choose k}(-2)^k)$
>
> $= {6\choose0} + (-2){6\choose1} + (4){6\choose2} + (-8){6\choose3}$
>
> $=1-12+60-160$
>
> $= -111$

But when I do the expansion on WolframAlpha, I see that $[x^0]=1$, $[x^1]=-12$, $[x^3]=-160$, so what am I doing wrong?

(I am following a similar idea to Trevor Gunn's answer in this question [In how many ways the sum of 5 thrown dice is 25?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2368302/in-how-many-ways-the-sum-of-5-thrown-dice-is-25))

Comment: Did you confuse $(-x)^k$ and $x^{-k}$?  Also, did you mean $x^3$ where you wrote $x^4$?

Comment: I dont think so. I dont see anywhere that should be an $x^{-k}$

Comment: How did you get $x^{3-k}$?

Comment: I might have worded the question confusingly, the $[x^3]$ is not multiplication, but rather finding the coefficient of the $x^3$ term in the equation that follows

Comment: Oh, then maybe you should say finding the coefficient of $x^3$ in ...

Comment: Your work is correct, and [this WolframAlpha link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?t=crmtb01&f=ob&i=taylor+series+(1-x)%5E-1(1-2x)%5E6) verifies it. What specifically did you see that made you think you were wrong?

Comment: @MarkDodds It seems the results you got from WolframAlpha are the coefficients in the power expansion of $(1-2x)^6$ instead of your full expression.

Comment: @JohnOmielan looking back i think that is what has happened. Thanks for clearing that up

Comment: @MarkDodds You're welcome. I noticed this when I saw the coefficients of the $x^0$, $x^1$ and $x^3$ matching your appropriate terms in your expression. However, I just realized that $\left[x^{60}\right]$ (which is what I assume you meant by $\left[x^{6}0\right]$) should be $0$ using $(1-2x)^6$, instead of $1$ as you wrote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Mike Earnest](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/177399/mike-earnest) confirmed in the comments, your work is correct. As I commented, and you've stated it's likely the case, the WolframAlpha results of $[x^0]=1$, $[x^1]=-12$, $[x^3]=-160$ probably come from the coefficients in the power expansion of $(1-2x)^6$ instead. You can see this directly from the first, second & fourth terms in your second last highlighted line, i.e.,

> $=1-12+60-160$